# How do I use serialize for an array attribute in a class using ActiveModel::Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm using a tableless model to create a form. I want to set one of the model attributes as an array

I know the following code doesn't work, but just showing what I want to do:

Model:

```
class Quote
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  attr_accessor :name, :length, :width, :city
  serialize :quantity, Array
end
```

Then reference in the form using:

```
f.text_field :quantity, multiple: true, class: 'form-control', type: 'number'
f.text_field :quantity, multiple: true, class: 'form-control', type: 'number'
```

How can I go about achieving this? Thank you.

Comment: can you not just add it to attr_accessor list and let the magic work?

Comment: When I added it to attr_accessor and submit the form, @quote.quantity returns nil. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: I think you could also take a look at Virtus gem: https://github.com/solnic/virtus

Comment: @massaskillz Are your params setup properly? I think you need to permit an array like so: `params.require(:quote).permit(:name, :length, :width, :city, :quantity => []`.

Comment: @BryanDimas thank you! That worked out for me.